# I want to know where can I find the generic or ideal DDR settings for u-boot?

Tags: linux, ram, u-boot

I was studying about the open source u-boot. Hence I wanted to know where can I find the generic DDR settings for u-boot? What are the ideal settings and likes? I do not need any specific SoC related details, just general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general case. Memory settings are, by their nature, *incredibly* hardware-dependent. Indeed, the optimal settings may vary based on the way that circuit traces are laid out from the CPU to memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that the setting are hardware-dependent and closely coupled. Say, for instance, I am using das u-boot as my starting point. Where can I get the code pertaining to the same? Can you please help!!!

Comment: The source code for U-Boot is available from their home page. For details on how to use it with your specific hardware, contact your board manufacturer. If it's custom, good luck, you're on your own.